# JSP + JERSEY web aplication... better to use static methods or instances?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, jersey

I have a JSP/Java web application which uses Jersey on a Tomcat server and this app must be live for months/years executing threads and maintaining live some objects.

What would be more efficient and safe? to use static methods on the jersey calls or to use instanced objects initialized on `ServletContextListener contextInitialized()` ?

Why?